# bootstrap combobox and selecting value after typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using `bootstrap combobox` plugin.

When you select from the combo NewYork it works fine, but if you type New and then try to select New York from the menu it doesn't work.

The example can be found [here](https://jsfiddle.net/neceegbv/5/).

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/poosanth/neceegbv/6/  change the `change` event to `click` event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** :

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poosanth/neceegbv/6)** change the `change` event to `click` event

```
$('.combobox').on('click', function(){
```

**Alternate**

Apply the if condition for `option value`

```
if(option.val()){
    alert('Value is ' + option.val());
  }
```

**[Demo fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/poosanth/neceegbv/7/)**

Answer (score 0):

It will be working fine:

```
$('.combobox').combobox();

var val = '', newVal = null;

$('.combobox').on('select', function(){

    newVal = $(this).val();

    if (newVal !== val) {
        val = newVal;
        alert('Value is ' + val);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#combobox').combobox();
$('#combobox').on('change', function(){
 if($(this).val()){
      console.log("You selected: "+$(this).val());
      alert('Value is ' + $(this).val());
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/master/css/bootstrap-combobox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/master/js/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>
<div>
    <select class="combobox" id="combobox">
      <option></option>
      <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
      <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
      <option value="NY">New York</option>
      <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
      <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Also check in fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/neceegbv/8/

Analyse this code with `class` and `id` you will see the difference.

Answer (score -1):

Your js fiddle snippet is right but there is issue on **alert** function. So remove alert function and put **console** method to find selected value like below snippet.

Hope helps you.

```js
$('.combobox').combobox();
$('.combobox').on('change', function(){
  var option = $(this).find('option:selected');
 if(option.length){
    console.log(option.val());
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/master/css/bootstrap-combobox.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox/master/js/bootstrap-combobox.js"></script>
<br><br>
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
     <select class="combobox form-control" id="combobox" data-placeholder="Enter City Name">
      <option></option>
       <option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option>
       <option value="CT">Connecticut</option>
       <option value="NY">New York</option>
       <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
       <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
     </select>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```